# Using the fourier series to analyze the motion of a finite string

Tags: homework-and-exercises, waves, fourier-transform

> Q: Find the Fourier series for the motion of a string of length L if
>
> (a) $y(x,0) = Ax(L-x); \frac{\partial y}{\partial t}_{t=0}=0.$
>
> (b) $y(x,0) = 0; \frac{\partial y}{\partial t}_{t=0}=Bx(L-x).$

I understand how to find the Fourier series to analyze a function at a specific time but I am not sure how to find the Fourier series in regards to both position and time.  I am not entirely sure I have the right equations on how to tackle this problem so I was hoping I could get some advice.  In the book, it gives an equation for the movement of the string as a function of position and time as: $$y(x,t) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty }A_n \sin(\frac{n\pi x}{L})\cos(\omega _n t - \delta_n).$$

I had a few thoughts on how I might use this function.

1. Assume no phase and replace $\omega_n$ with $n \omega_1$ giving: $y(x,t) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty }A_n \sin(\frac{n\pi x}{L})\cos(n \omega_1 t).$
2. Find some way of replacing elements of the summation with $C_n$, which is involved in the answer to both part (a) and (b).

Beyond these $2$ simple ideas I am quite lost with this problem.  Any guidance with this problem would be very much appreciated.

Here are the answers to the questions, in case that helps:

> $$y(x,t) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty }C_n \sin(\frac{n\pi x}{L})$$ where
>
> (a) $C_n = \begin{cases}
>  & 8AL^2\cos(n \omega_1 t)/(n \pi)^3 \mbox{,  n  odd}\\
>  & 0 \mbox{,  n even}
> \end{cases}$
>
> (b) $C_n = \begin{cases}
>  & 8BL^2\sin(n \omega_1 t)/ n^4 \pi^3 \omega_1 \mbox{,   n odd} \\
>  & 0 \mbox{,  n even}
> \end{cases}$

Comment: The trick is to multiply by $\sin(k \pi x/L)$ and integrate from $x=0$ to $L$.

Comment: Do you mind being a bit more specific?  I'm not sure what I should be multiplying by $sin(k \pi x / L)$

Comment: Also you only need to find Fourier series at $t=0$, it is really a function of position only.

Comment: @ja72, if I am only finding the Fourier series at $t=0$, wouldn't that just mean $y(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty }B_n \sin(\frac{n\pi x}{L})$?

Comment: You only need the Fourier series for the initial conditions in order to find $A_n$ and $\delta_n$. That's why you do it at zero time.

Comment: So doing that out, I'm getting that $A_n = \frac {8AL^2}{(n \pi)^3} $ for odd $n$.  I don't understand how I proceed from there.

Comment: @ja72 - "Fourier series for the _motion_ ..." implies it is not simply at t=0

Comment: See my answer for more details.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is $$ y(x,t) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sin(n \pi \frac{x}{\ell}) \left(S_n \sin(n \pi  \frac{c t}{\ell}) + C_n \cos(n \pi \frac{c t}{\ell}) \right) $$

where $c$ is the wave speed from the wave equation. The problem now is to find the Fourier coefficients $S_n$ and $C_n$ for the given initial conditions. Consider the general IC of

$$ \begin{aligned} y(x,0) &= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sin(n \pi \frac{x}{\ell}) C_n & y(x,0) &= Y(x) \\ \dot{y}(x,0) & =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sin(n \pi \frac{x}{\ell}) S_n \frac{n \pi c}{\ell} & \dot{y}(x,0) & = V(x) \end{aligned}$$

You find the coefficients by calculating the following (at $t=0$)

$$ \int \limits_0^\ell \sin(k \pi \frac{x}{\ell}) y(x,0) {\rm d}x = \int \limits_0^\ell \sin(k \pi \frac{x}{\ell}) Y(x) {\rm d}x$$
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} C_n \int \limits_0^\ell \sin(k \pi \frac{x}{\ell})\sin(n \pi \frac{x}{\ell})    {\rm d}x= \int \limits_0^\ell \sin(k \pi x) Y(x) {\rm d}x$$
$$  C_k \frac{\ell}{2}= \int \limits_0^\ell \sin(k \pi x) Y(x) {\rm d}x$$
$$ C_n = \frac{2}{\ell} \int \limits_0^\ell \sin(n \pi x) Y(x) {\rm d}x$$

And similarly for the velocities
$$ \int \limits_0^\ell \sin(k \pi \frac{x}{\ell}) \dot{y}(x,0) {\rm d}x = \int \limits_0^\ell \sin(k \pi \frac{x}{\ell}) V(x) {\rm d}x$$
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{k \pi c}{\ell} S_k \int \limits_0^\ell \sin(k \pi \frac{x}{\ell})\sin(n \pi \frac{x}{\ell})    {\rm d}x= \int \limits_0^\ell \sin(k \pi x) V(x) {\rm d}x$$
$$ \frac{k \pi c}{\ell}  S_k \frac{\ell}{2}= \int \limits_0^\ell \sin(k \pi x) V(x) {\rm d}x$$
$$ S_n = \frac{2}{\pi c n } \int \limits_0^\ell \sin(n \pi x) V(x) {\rm d}x$$

Once you have the coefficients $S_n$ and $C_n$ at initial conditions, they remain the same with time (they are constants) so you just use $y(x,t)$ to find the shape at a later time.

Comment: I really appreciate your effort in writing up this answer but I don't understand what you're doing.  If I get to $ y(x,t) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sin(n \pi \frac{x}{L}) C_n$ then the rest of the answer follows fairly easily.  The issue is in how to arrive at the summation from the given initial conditions

Comment: Perhaps I should add, $C_n$ is a distinctly different thing than $A_n$ and $B_n$.  It isn't just different notation, the textbook I am using (AP French) treats them completely differently.

Comment: I use $C_n$ and $S_n$ for cosines and sines to distinguish between $A_n$ and $\delta_n$ for amplitude and phase. You can convert from one to another using polar coordinate transforms.

Comment: $$ A_n = \sqrt{C_n^2+S_n^2} \\ \tan \delta_n = -\frac{S_n}{C_n}$$